# Configure spring boot with Oracle DB SSL/TCPS

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle12c

I need to configure Spring boot with TCPS for Oracle DB, I've found an article for normal java program but couldn't find any resources for spring boot configuration

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", "test");
    props.setProperty("password", "test123");

    //Single sign on
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cwallet.sso");
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","SSO");
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","cwallet.sso");
    props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","SSO");
     //Load the database driver 
    try
    {
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=999.999.999.999)(PORT=1522))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxxx)))";

        Security.addProvider(new OraclePKIProvider());
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,props);
        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
    }
```

Comment: please share your experience how you could resolve this problem? am looking for solution for this problem.